Testing with PHP Infection
I cover my project with unit tests. I'm using infection and codeception v5. Also I install bypass-finals extension, cause project has a lot of final classes. I guess because of the presence of final classes the library gives me inaccurate coverage results. Or is it just a display bug? I don't know.
I use:

PHP ​​8.3
Infection v0.29.0
Codeception v5.1.2
Bypass-finals v1.8.0

I wrote tests. They are successful, and the infection metric is as follows:
Metrics:
    Mutation Score Indicator (MSI): 72%
    Mutation Code Coverage: 72%
    Covered Code MSI: 100%

When I open the generated report and look at the killed mutants, I see the following:
️ Codeception PHP Testing Framework v5.1.2 https://stand-with-ukraine.pp.ua
[Groups] infection 

Tests.Unit Tests (2) ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
- KernelTest: Creating kernel
E KernelTest: Creating kernel(0.01s)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Time: 00:00.349, Memory: 22.00 MB

There was 1 error:
1) KernelTest: Creating kernel
 Test  tests/Unit/Kernel/KernelTest.php:testCreatingKernel
                                                                                                                                         
  [PHPUnit\Framework\MockObject\Generator\ClassIsFinalException] Class "Kernel\KernelFactory" is declared "final" and cannot be doubled  

And I became interested in how reliable the numbers from the metric shown above are, because when I removed the "final" from one class, the metric changed and the MSI decreased:
Metrics:
         Mutation Score Indicator (MSI): 71%
         Mutation Code Coverage: 72%
         Covered Code MSI: 98%

Question: how can this be avoided? It seems to me that I see imaginary results of the work done. Maybe I should ask the developers of the infection directly?

Where did you configure bypass-globals to run? i.e. where did you add DG\BypassFinals::enable(); as described on the README? It sounds like maybe when Infection is running your code, the bypass is not being enabled.

@IMSoP, thanks for the answer. I added this call to bootstrap.php, which I specified in the Codeception settings. It works currently because when I run tests with codecept run Unit, all tests pass successfully.
Do I need to call DG\BypassFinals::enable(); in index.php as well?
